# Return a percentage sign in Lua string.format

Tags: lua

In a modification script I'm developing for an online game, I'm attempting to display the current percentage of a number.

```
function()
    local z = math.max(0, UnitPower("player")) / math.max(1, UnitPowerMax("player")) * 100;
    return string.format("%.f", z);
end
```

**The code above displays the percentage correctly.**

However, I am having a difficult time getting the actual percentage sign to show up without throwing errors everywhere.

I've tried adding `print("%%")` before ending the function as well as after the function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Writing a Weak Aura for WoW? Well... technically written :)

Comment: Yes, actually. Wow, this was ages ago - what a necro! :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `string.format`, like `printf` in C, requires the percent sign to be doubled when you want it verbatim. This is *not* the case for `print` or `io.write` functions !

So you certainly want this :

```
function()
  local z = math.max(0, UnitPower("player")) / math.max(1, UnitPowerMax("player")) * 100;
  return string.format("%.f %%", z);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

```
function()
    local z = math.max(0, UnitPower("player")) / math.max(1, UnitPowerMax("player")) * 100;
    return string.format("%.f", z) .. "%%";
end
```

Just added `.. "%%"`; the value shown is now **100%** (where 100 is the current percentage.

Super late edit:
This was part of some custom code being entered into an addon for the video game World of Warcraft, and this is the solution for the goal I wanted to achieve because the author was calling `string.format()` around the "custom code" input. Refer to the other answer on this question for the standard `Lua` solution.

Comment: Yeah, if this works, then the caller of this function must be calling string.format() again on the string returned.